# php default include folder

Tags: php, include, server-side, server-side-includes

Php files can be included from any folder. But are there any benefits to include a php file from the default php folder, which in my case is `c:/php/pear/...`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you have libraries or frameworks that can be used as building blocks for more than one application (for example if you host multiple sites, or subdomains), you can use a single folder for easy updating of the libraries when needed. Other than that, each webapp/site you have can have its own includes.

FYI, use this notation I find it better:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/..<location of your include file>");
```

this also works for include_once, require, require_once